# Google Apps Script - Callback for class methods used in webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, asynccallback

I have a GAS that i'm submitting a form in my webapp to. It does the following:

1. opens a template doc containing placeholders (in the format of `##form_field_name##`) corresponding to the names of the form fields on the form
2. makes a copy of the template and saves it to the appropriate location
3. iterates through the submitted values and does a `body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);` to populate the values into the doc
4. does a `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');` to get rid of the place holder strings for any fields left blank (as they are not currently submitted with the form)

I'm ending up with a document that looks like the user did not submit ANY data at all. My guess is that it's because the #4 is running before #3 finishes. Is there any way to specify #4 as a callback? Something like:

```
body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val, () => {
    body.replaceText('##.*##', '');
});
```

Here is the code for the function that does the `replaceText()`ing:

```
/**
 * Iterate through obj of keys/values and replace ##key## 
 * with value in doc 
**/
function doFindAndReplace(obj, doc) {
  try {
    //body = doc.getBody();
    var id = doc.getId();
    var _doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
    var body = _doc.getBody();
    //var doc = _doc;
    //Logger.log(body);
    for (var prop in obj) {
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var val = obj[prop];
        var key = prop.indexOf('intake') === 0 ? prop.toUpperCase() : '';
        //Logger.log(key + ' = ' + val);
        //Logger.log(typeof val);
        body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);
        _doc.saveAndClose();
        var _doc2 = DocumentApp.openById(id);
        body = _doc2.getBody();
        body.replaceText('##.*##', '');
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    Logger.log('doFindAndReplace() | ' + e);
    errors.push({ 
      fxn: 'doFindAndReplace', 
      msg: e, 
      custom: 'id=' + id
    });
    return false;
  }
  return doc;
}
```

The parameter `obj` is an object containing the submitted form data and `doc` is a reference to the newly created document in which the find-and-replace is taking place.

If nothing like that is possible, I was thinking about adding an `onOpen` trigger that wold run the #4 (`body.replaceText('##.*##', '');`). This would require that the user opens the doc for the first time while online and a huge part of the use case is using the newly creatted document offline.

Can anyone suggest another workaround?

** **EDIT** **
I updated my code (reflected above) to `saveAndClose()` and then re-open before running the 2nd `replaceText()`. I get the following error:

> Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated

I know, you'd think it would come *after* the `saveAndClose()`. But thta's the line the error points at and even if I remove the rest of the lines after it, the same error occurs.

If I remove the `saveAndClose()` line with the code as is, I get my original problem again.

I don't think this is the same issue as [Weird Behaviour with DriveApp.getFileById()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278818/weird-behaviour-with-driveapp-getfilebyid)

** **EDIT 2** **
Here's an example of an object passed to the function:

```
{
intake_activity_level: "Normal",
intake_assessment_comments: "",
intake_client_addr: "1600 Fake St XXXX, XX 12345",
intake_client_email: "xxx@gmail.com",
intake_client_name: "Dan Tester",
intake_client_phone: "(917) 555-1212", 
intake_consent: "yes", 
intake_consent_owner: "Jim David",
intake_food_intake: "Decreased",
intake_gen_food: "",
intake_gen_health: "sit dolam amet",
intake_gen_meds: "re et sapien et, consectetur rhoncus lacus. Aliqua Vivamus ipsum diam, venenatis a turpis eget, volu",
intake_gen_reasons: "Lorem ipsum",
intake_gen_vaccine: "Yes",
intake_misc_comments: "",
intake_misc_descriptor: "wood",
intake_panting: "Increased",
intake_pet_breed: "Pug",
intake_pet_dob: "8/11/2015",
intake_pet_name: "FLuffy",
intake_pet_sex: "Spayed Female",
intake_pet_species: "Dog",
intake_pet_weight: "140lbs",
intake_sleep: "Increased",
intake_source: "Sally Balls",
intake_stiffness: "Normal",
intake_symptoms: "coughing, belching or gas",
intake_vet: "Urban Vet",
intake_voice: "Increased",
intake_water_intake: "Decreased"
}
```

and a watered-down version of the Document can be accessed [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nYQ2RVEAbOga5Bwxjq6WxPnEDXv17n9bnK2tp83GfS4/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your issue probably stems from a recent bug related to form submissions. Basically, there are "phantom" submissions where forms are somehow automatically submitted without corresponding data. Search stackoverflow for related topics and you should find various workarounds for the issue.

Comment: no the GAS is receiving the data. When I remove `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');` the document populates just fine. I just need a way to prevent that line from running until the previous `replaceText()` call has finished.

Comment: GAS is synchronous. You're missing something else. Could you  show your full script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird Behaviour with DriveApp.getFileById()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278818/weird-behaviour-with-driveapp-getfilebyid)

Comment: I'd try and [Document.saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document.html#saveAndClose()) between steps 3 and 4.  Get the Id before you save and close and then reopen it again with the id.  It will certainly slow things down though.

Comment: @TheMaster - code posed above

Comment: @Cooper - when I try 'doc.saveAndClose()', I get `Document is closed, its contents cannot be updated.`

Comment: Well.  I also said reopen it.  I'm treating it like a Spreadsheet flush.

Comment: i know... it's not making it past `doc.saveAndClose()`. That's the line that is causing the error. Even If I remove everything after it (re-opening the doc and doing the 2nd `replaceText()`), it gives the same error with the line number pointing to  `doc.saveAndClose()`

Comment: @Daveh0 Can you provide a sample value of `obj` and the sample Document for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. I would like to confirm `var key = prop.indexOf('intake') === 0 ? prop.toUpperCase() : '';`. Although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, in this case, when `intake` is the top letter of `prop`, `prop.toUpperCase()` is returned. If `intake` is included in `prop`, `''` is returned. If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks for looking into this. Yes the line `var key = prop.indexOf('intake') === 0 ? prop.toUpperCase()` is producing the desired result. None of the needed data is being reset to an empty string. An object with sample data as well as a link to a sample doc are in my post above under ** **EDIT 2** **

Comment: @Daveh0 Thank you for replying and the additional information. From your question and the additional question, I proposed a modified script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to replace `'##' + key + '##'` to `va;` with `body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);` using `obj`.
- You want to replace `##.*##` to `''` with `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');`.
- You want to run `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');` after all `body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);` were run.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

In your current script, `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');` is put in the for loop. By this, only `intake_activity_level: "Normal",` is used and other objects are not used. In this case, after the 1st `body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);` is run, all `##key##` values are removed by `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var val = obj[prop];
    var key = prop.indexOf('intake') === 0 ? prop.toUpperCase() : '';
    //Logger.log(key + ' = ' + val);
    //Logger.log(typeof val);
    body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);
    _doc.saveAndClose();
    var _doc2 = DocumentApp.openById(id);
    body = _doc2.getBody();
    body.replaceText('##.*##', '');
  }
}
```

To:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var val = obj[prop];
    var key = prop.indexOf('intake') === 0 ? prop.toUpperCase() : '';
    body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);
  }
}
body.replaceText('##.*##', '');
```

- In this modification, at first, `body.replaceText('##' + key + '##', val);` is run in the for loop. And then, `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');` is run at the outside of the for loop.

#### Note:

- If `saveAndClose()` is required, how about putting `doc.saveAndClose()` after `body.replaceText('##.*##', '');`?

Comment: uuuuuuugh!! I can't believe I didn't catch that the 2nd `replaceText()` was INSIDE the loop!! Obviously that fixed it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Daveh0 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.